# Using image as borders in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, border

Is there an optimal way to use asset images as borders for a container? I'm looking for an equivalent to the CSS attribute border-image.

I have an image that I want to use as a frame around a Container. However, if the Container has different size compare to the original image, the details on the corner of the images will be stretched. I would like to preserve these corner details even when the Container have different size.

The only way I can think of as a work around is using Stack with 8 Images that will surround my main Container (4 for corners, and 4 for edges) and cut the original images into corners and edges. However, I think this is not the best solution so I would love to hear some advices if someone has run into this problem before.

Comment: check [centerSlice](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage/centerSlice.html)

Comment: @pskink This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: sure, your welcome